# Error deleting SQL Server local database

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm doing a project in Visual Studio 2012 and it involves working with the given database. As I add the `database.mdf` to the project (asp.data folder) I got a connection error, but nothing out of the ordinary. To "repair" the database we are supposed to enter this into cmd

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
SqlLocalDB.exe delete v11.0
```

At school everything worked fine, but at home I got this error in cmd

> Delete of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error:
>   Requested operation on LocalDB instance cannot be performed because specified instance is currently in use. Stop the instance and try again.

What do I have to close/do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make sure you have stopped the database before deleting it.

You can check the current state by running this:

```
SqlLocalDb info "MyInstance"
```

and stop it by running :

```
SqlLocalDb stop   "MyInstance"
```

Once stopped you should be able to delete the instance.

[This](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) is a nice guide on installing and deleting express databases.